# Validating menu tab in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

In my django application,I am creating new report using django session,and my application contain 3 tabs namely `Reports,Search and New Report`.`Tab` highlight says that the application is in which page.If user clicks `New report`,the New report tab will be highlighted.

User can view all the reports by clicking the report link from `Report` tab.

If the user clicks any one of the report namely `"report id 5"`in Report tab,that will open the report under `New report` Tab,so the `New report` menu gets highlighted.But i want it to not highlight because `New report` Tab is for creating only new report,while seeing the existing report i should not highlight the `New report` Tab.How to do it using django.

views.py

```
def method(request):
    Some code
    return render(request, sometemplate.html',
                 {'
                  'newreport_menu': True,
                 })
```

In menu tab,i validated like this

```
<li {% if newreport_menu %}class="current"{% endif %}><a href="{% url incident.views.new_report %}">New Report</a></li>
```

Now "New Report" menu is always gets highlighted for creating new report and if user click the existing report from Report Tab.But it should not highlight if the user clicks the existing report.

How to do this.

Thanks

Comment: in view -- return render(request, sometemplate.html',
                 {'
                  'newreport_class': "current",
                 })                                                    in template -- <li class="{{newreport_class}}" > .... </li>

Comment: Tip: Compare what's the difference between new report and existing report. Basically, when you say new report, the field is blank while existing report is already populated so think about the difference and you solved your problem

Comment: @catherine New report includes 5 pages and all the pages are not mandatory so user can skip some pages and can open that after some while to update the data.If possible to do it in that way can you explain me or i am using django session for creating report is any way to to using session,Can i get any reply for this please

Comment: I want to highlight the New Report menu while creating a report,if i am reopen the same report afterwards i don't want to highlight the New Report menu,can you tell me how to do it.